# Displaying multiple categories on a QGIS map?

Tags: qgis

I'm tasked with displaying reserve data on a map but also displaying the category data for each site even though they overlap with other reserves. E.g. I have a category, "Birdwatching" which applies to 50 sites whilst the category, "Grassland" applies to 30 sites but overlaps with the birdwatching category thus a site could have "birdwatching and grasslands".

I created a layer for every category, so a user could select "birdwatching" and view the 50 of 100 reserves that meet this rule. But how do I go about composing a map that includes all ten categories?

Comment: Take a look at the options for "fill style" for your layer symbology. You can either choose some kind of point or line-based fill, or adjust transparency levels so that other layers will show through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP suggests that the sites across the 10 layers are the same and a single site can be a grassland and a bird watching site at the same time.

The solution to this is not to create a layer for every category but rather have one layer and create a column for every category and fill it with 1 if the site belongs to this category and 0 if not. Then you could represent the sites using the rule-based styling.

**Edit:**

Based on an additional comment by the OP, a good option to represent the attributes of the sites is to use Layer Diagram Options in QGIS (Second button on the label toolbar). Using a rule-based symbology with 10 attributes can potentially create lots of classes.

[image]

You have the option to represent the data as:

- A pie chart

[image]

- Text diagram

[image]

- Histogram

[image]

The tool settings are rather straightforward to use.

Comment: This is something I also considered (data is already displayed yes/no) but i'm confounded by how to compose a map that displays this information as that is part of my instructions. I understand how a GIS interface could answer the question, E.g. User selects the categories they are interested in then it shows relevant sites but I don't know how show that on a single or multiple maps for the sake of a report. Is it possible to have a symbol segmented based on the number of categories for that site?

Comment: This seems like a solution but QGIS crashes each time I select the categories. I reduced it two categories and it created the pie chart but it was not filled in for any of the sites.

Comment: Did you add the attributes to the assigned attributes?

Comment: I completed the following: Selected layer>diagram options>pie chart>selected the 10 attributes from available attributes>clicked green cross to place them into assigned attributes>clicked ok> layer appears with circle over each node but no segments>qgis crashes.

Comment: It would help if you can add what version of QGIS you're using and on which OS and the type of dataset you have. I can't help you with the crash problem but maybe someone more knowledgeable could chime in. I also believe you should post this issue as a new question as the nature of GIS.SE is one question per topic and your initial question was, I suppose, answered.

Comment: Can't argue with that.

Comment: Just wanted to say, I found out why my GIS was crashing. The layer I was working was a delimited text layer, after saving as .shp file I stopped getting crashes. I also had to edit my database to replace the "yes" and "null" values with "1" and "0" to get the segments to appear.

Comment: Glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use rule based styling to use more then one category. There are many online tips guides and tutorials on rule based styling in qgis.